# basic java database organization

Tags: java, database

I'm working on this database type program for school. so far I've been able to make this part of the code fully functional:

```
import jpb.*;
//jpb is a package that lets me use SimpleIO as you'll see below

public class PhoneDirectory {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PhoneRecord[] records = new PhoneRecord[100];
    int numRecords = 0;

    // Display list of commands
    System.out.println("Phone directory commands:\n" +
                       "  a - Add a new phone number\n" +
                       "  f - Find a phone number\n" +
                       "  q - Quit\n");

    // Read and execute commands
    while (true) {

      // Prompt user to enter a command
      SimpleIO.prompt("Enter command (a, f, or q): ");
      String command = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();

      // Determine whether command is "a", "f", "q", or
      // illegal; execute command if legal.
      if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {

        // Command is "a". Prompt user for name and number,
        // then create a phone record and store it in the
        // database.
        if (numRecords < records.length) {
          SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new name: ");
          String name = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
          SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new phone number: ");
          String number = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
          records[numRecords] = 
            new PhoneRecord(name, number);
          numRecords++;
        } else
          System.out.println("Database is full");

      } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {

        // Command is "f". Prompt user for search key.
        // Search the database for records whose names begin
        // with the search key. Print these names and the
        // corresponding phone numbers.
        SimpleIO.prompt("Enter name to look up: ");
        String key = SimpleIO.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
          String name = records[i].getName().toLowerCase();
          if (name.startsWith(key))
            System.out.println(records[i].getName() + " " + 
                               records[i].getNumber());
        }

      } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        // Command is "q". Terminate program.
        return;

      } else {
        // Command is illegal. Display error message.
        System.out.println("Command was not recognized; " +
                           "please enter only a, f, or q.");
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}

// Represents a record containing a name and a phone number
class PhoneRecord {
  private String name;
  private String number;

  // Constructor
  public PhoneRecord(String personName, String phoneNumber) {
    name = personName;                       
    number = phoneNumber;
  }

  // Returns the name stored in the record
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // Returns the phone number stored in the record
  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do a few things, and they're probably simple solutions I'm just looking over. I need to make a command "d" for delete that will prompt for a name and delete all records that match. I tried using the same approach as the "f" command where partial matches are allowed, but again I couldn't get it to work.

Next I need to modify the *f* command so that it lines up names and numbers in columns. I tried to force the string to be a certain length by making it = to the array length to no avail, it just returns looking blank. essentially it needs to look like this:

```
Smith, John    555-5556
Shmoe, Joe     565-5656
```

and I need to set records to 1 instead of 100 and have in double in size every time it gets full. I haven't messed with this yet, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Because the requirement is to be able to remove records i would recommend using an ArrayList which grows dynamically and you are able to easily remove records.

It is declarer like this:

```
ArrayList<PhoneRecord> records = new ArrayList<PhoneRecord>();
```

and you add like this:

```
records.add(PhoneRecord(name, number)));
```

you can remove a record like this:

```
records.remove(i);
```

to remove the ith record of the list.

the current size of the list is given by records.size() function.

As for your second question you can use string formatting to tell it to format the name for a specified number of characters for example you could use this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s%15s", records[i].getName(), records[i].getNumber());
```

In this example will be added space characters before the telephone in order the total number of characters will be 15.

So if your number is 555-5556 then 7 space blank characters will be added before the number.